# Jaxx transaction stays on pending confirmation

Tags: transactions, jaxx

Last night I tried to send ether to an address from my jaxx wallet. But seems that the fee which I set (80000 gas limit -> 10 Gwei) is very low and the transaction stayed in pending status for over 10 hours. Can I somehow cancel this from the jaxx wallet and resend it - I don't see such a button. Or to restore my wallet to MyEtherWallet and try to resend the transaction with bigger fee from there. If the second is completed is the first will be cancelled automatically when there are no sufficient funds once it is tried to be sent some day in the future.
Thanks for your help,
Georgi

Comment: I am having the same issue with mine since yesterday. I was never asked about any gas, I just approved what they requested as payment. Same issue , still pending ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer, as it should apply to Jaxx as well:
**https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/35207/20276**

---

What you want to do is re-submit your transaction, using the **SAME `nonce`** as before. As long as your transaction has **not already been confirmed** on the blockchain *(make sure of this FIRST),* then just about any Ethereum client *(Jaxx included)* will pull the same **`nonce`** value dynamically from its blockchain provider and simply override the previous transaction.