# Cancel a transaction that has not been pushed via Mist

Tags: transactions, mist

I submitted a transaction via Mist with the fee slider at the leftmost position. Nothing happened for a day now, so I suspect that the displayed gas price has been to small, although Mist told me that the transaction is likely to be executed in a few minutes.

I searched the internet on how to cancel a transaction and found that in principle there is no way.

However, the transaction does not even show up on etherscan yet, so I suspect that it might not even have been published(?). If it is so, is there a way to stop Mist from doing so?

I also found that you can send another transaction with a higher gas price but the same nonce such that only the latter transaction is executed. I could send a zero-valued transaction to myself with the same nonce. Is there a possibility in Mist to find out the Nonce of the displayed transaction and to send another transaction with the same nonce?

**Edit:** The linked "possible duplicate" does not explain how to get the nonce from a transaction in Mist and submit a new transaction with the same nonce.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reverse or cancel a transaction or recover lost ethers?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25866/how-can-i-reverse-or-cancel-a-transaction-or-recover-lost-ethers)

Comment: Okay - I've retracted my close vote as I think I jumped the gun a little. This question is specifically asking how to do this via Mist.

Answer (score 1):

I do not regularly use **[Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases)** myself, but I believe that its wallet is the same as **[https://wallet.ethereum.org/,](https://wallet.ethereum.org/)** which I do use quite often. In which case, simply repost your transaction using a higher fee. Until it confirms on the blockchain, Mist *should* use the same nonce as the original transaction.

To determine the best gas price to use next time, I would recommend using **https://ethgasstation.info/** and check the **`Gas Price SafeLow`** number.

Comment: I already sent the transaction via Metamask because I suspected Mist isn't working. So I would prefer it not to be sent. By now I haven't even enough funds in my wallet for the old transaction to be executed, anyway (I suppose you can't have negative funds in your wallet). And also the old transaction still does not show on etherscan.

Comment: Correct. So because the network cannot see your transaction, Metamask was able to just re-use the same `nonce`, and override the previous attempt using Mist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cancel a tx, normaly it will been eareased in 2 days beacause it was stuck to many time in the mempool. (If you have put the slider left your tx will never pass)

And try to find it here : https://etherscan.io/txsPending it is all the tx not passed because they are to young or because they have a to low gas price.

And why mist print you it will pass in few minutes ? Because your node havn't all the mempool, (mist didn't know all the tx, it saw just a litle part of them and it think: "there is only these tx ? so a litle gas will pass". But why you didn't know all the tx ? Probably because your node are in desktop and your ISP box havn't upnp so your node isn't visible from outside so you can go on other node for download blocks, you can send your tx to other node but other can't pull you block and tx, so you never receive other tx except if your wallet do this by them self, but they do that not very often (close to never))

Comment: That's kind of the point: if I enter my address on etherscan it shows me that there is no transaction pending. So I supposed Mist didn't even publish it and I could prevent it from even trying (practically 'canceling' the transaction)

Comment: If you don't see it is probably it have been already eareased (geth havn't a know bug of not pushing tx, and it shouldn't have one). So you can export the blockchain with geth export go to .ethereum/ and remove geth folder then reimport the blockchain with geth import.